# Placeholder text for birthday is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

In your profile settings you have a field for birthday with placeholder text:

[image]

I get up to "only used for displa..." and don't know what else it really says.  Is it only used for display purposes?  Can we add a tooltip to fully show what the placeholder text really says?

Comment: How is this an issue?

Comment: @JustDoIt:  The words cut off.  Not good UX.

Comment: My question remains unanswered @Makoto but I guess...

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me, it's only used for displa

Comment: so we see the word "displa" and can't make up the remaining character? @mikeTheLiar

Comment: How do you know if there exists anything after the word display?  Birthdays are sensitive topics for some people.

Comment: Hey guys, c'mon, I was clearly just trying to make a jo

Comment: It says "YYYY/MM/DD, only used for displaying age" ... Trust me, I have ninja eyes.

Comment: They won't have to worry, *Private information (not shown publicly)* If they really worried about what that watermark says, I'm sure they would've read that part as well.

Comment: @JustDoIt ...How is it not an issue? A bug in the UX is still a bug.

Comment: @JustDoIt Since the watermark says the information is used to display your age, and the header (in contradiction) says it is not shown publicly at all, it is quite relevant. Especially since anyone noticing when your age change will know your birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed (we moved "only used for displaying age" in the label), it will be live after our next production build.

Answer (score 9):

This is the complete placeholder

```
YYYY/MM/DD, only used for displaying age
```

Got this from the source code of that page.

**In chrome**:

Right click and choose `view page source` and you can see this line

```
<input name="Birthday" type="text" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD, only used for displaying age" maxlength="50" tabindex="22"
data-default=""
data-site=""
value="" />
```

Comment: I understand that I can get this from the page, that is not the point.  Ux means there is no ambiguity for non techies too.

Comment: @JonH Ya. I agree with that. You posted `don't know what else it really says.` So only I posted this as an answer

Comment: This text seems too long for any placeholder. Shouldn't we have some shorter text that fits in the text box or increase the text box size (not recommended) to show the complete text? If this is not possible have a tool tip as mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need for a tooltip. I would argue that the information shouldn't be in the text box to begin with. It should part of the field name, and shortened.

> Birthday (will display age)

[image: mockup]

As you can see, I would personally make the parenthetical text a bit smaller or lighter colored, but also use a bit of color to call attention to it, since it completely contradicts the other parenthetical statement "(not shown publicly)".

(Still submitting because I took the time to make a mockup.)

Answer (score 2):

Just some notes while we are there:

- the age, because of the profile page updates, is only displayed in the network profile. I think this will be removed eventually, to be inline with the per-site profiles.
- despite being listed under "private information (not shown publicly)", the birthday isn't really private, at least because of revealing the age.

Answer (score 2):

I'd solve it by moving the description into the label. Whether it's just there, it's in a less obvious font (smaller, gray, etc.), or it's hidden under a tooltip of some sort. This makes sense to me because the "only used for displaying age" is an alert that users should be seeing with "Birthday", but "YYYY/MM/DD" is instructions for inputting your data.

```
<div class="col-4 with-padding">
    <label>
        Birthday
        <span class="someLessObviousFont">(only used for displaying age)</span>
    </label>
    <input name="Birthday" type="text" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" maxlength="10" tabindex="22">
</div>
```

*I also changed the maxlength from 50 to 10 because...why was it 50?*

Comment: "why was it 50"? I obviously can't speak for SE, but ever mistyped anything in a field with a max length and thus had to backspace back to it (because of buggy javascript solution) or had to remove the typo before being able to finish what you were typing? I hate that with a passion.